# Prove $\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$ that if $n \equiv 3 \pmod 6$ then $36 \mid (n^2 + 27)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

> Prove $\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$ that if $n \equiv 3 \pmod 6$ then $36 \mid (n^2 + 27)$

I know that $n \not\mid 6$ therefore, $6 \not\mid n$ and $6$ is not a multiple of $n$. But it's not helping me prove:

$$ 36 \mid (n^2 + 27)  $$

How can I prove this?

Comment: I've edited the post for you to use Mathjax/LaTeX for formatting the mathematical expressions. It is not too difficult to learn to use. It does take some time, but it is worth it, and is much easier (and generally produces nicer output) than searching for, copying, and pasting the equivalent unicode symbols.

Comment: As a hint: try writing $n=6k+3$ for some integer $k$, and substitute that into the expression $n^2+27$.

Comment: @Dylan2 I just wrote an answer and while I was typing it your comment appeared here. (so maybe put your comment up as another answer...)

Comment: $n=6k+3$ implies $n^2+27=36k^2+36k+36$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What $n\equiv3 \pmod6$ means is that $\exists k\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n=6k+3$. We need to prove that $36\mid(n^2+27)$ so plugging in $6k+3$ for $n$ we get $$(6k+3)^2+27=36k^2+36k+36$$ This is divisible by $36$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: You actually don't know that $n$ doesn't divide $6,$ for example $n=3$ satisfies your assumption. However you do know that there is an integer $k$ for which $n=6k+3.$ Now substitute that into $n^2+27$ and expand, and see what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Computation-free approach: the condition $n \equiv 3 \pmod{6}$ implies $n^2 \equiv 9 \pmod{36}$, which is exactly what we need.